# getDay() errors with Invalid Date in some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, air

I have the following string: "2012-12-10T23:40:41Z"

My goal is to get the day as a number (0-6)... sun-sat

I pass this string as follows:

```
var input = "2012-12-10T23:40:41Z";
var day = new Date(input).getDay();
alert(day);
```

This works just fine in Chrome, but in the adobe air webkit view, it errors with, "Invalid Date"

Any suggestions on finding a way to get the day that is supported by older browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a comment.

To manually parse a [javascript ISO8601 date string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), split it into parts and pass it to the date constructor. Note that javascript date strings should always be UTC (Z), so:

```
function parseISOdateString(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]))
}
```

You can add bells and whistles to the above to validate the string and the resultant date object if you like.

Note that according to ES5, invalid date strings given to [`Date.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) (e.g. 2012-12-00) should return `NaN`, but some browsers will create a date object for 2012-11-30. The above will return a date object for invalid strings, so if consistency with the spec is required:

```
function parseISOdateString(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]))
  return (d.getUTCFullYear() == s[0] && d.getUTCDate() == s[2])? d : NaN;
}
```

That will return `NaN` for invalid strings like "2012-12-00"

Answer (score 4):

Prior to ES5, there was no standard way of parsing a date (each host implemented their own way of parsing). Since ES5, dates must be in the ISO8601 format in order to be parseable in strict mode.

For maximum portability, you should parse the date manually.

Comment: @RachelDRoy, you could use regular expressions or substrings for example.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/) should prove helpful, even though it is a bit old. The issue is that ISO 8601 style dates only got support in Javascript 1.8.5.